# I got a custom autocomplete and want to make KEYUP and KEYDOWN work

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need someone to head me to the right direction (I've done mostly back-end stuff and recently my JS experience has involved mostly jQuery, not too many low-level programming in JS, so I'm lacking the JS patterns on how to implement it properly).

https://jsfiddle.net/honesta/4jef9k29/6/

```
        // Keydown
        $(this).on('keydown', function(event) {
            switch(event.keyCode) {
                case 27: // escape
                    this.hide();
                    break;
                // case 40: // keydown
                    //
                default:
                    this.request();
                    break;
            }
        });
```

I have this custom autocomplete, trying to make the keyboard KEYUP and KEYDOWN working to navigate the list. Any idea where do I start? What would be the best approach? Or some similar example where I can base my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a bit complicated because of the bootstrap `:hover` state on dropdown items.

```
$(this).on('keydown', function(event){
   switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 27: // escape
        this.hide();
        break;
      case 40: //Keydown
        event.preventDefault();
        var active_li = $('.li_active').removeClass('li_active').next();
        if(!active_li.length) active_li = $('ul.dropdown-menu li:eq(0)');
        active_li.addClass('li_active').find('a').trigger('mouseenter');
        break;
      case 38: //Keyup 
        event.preventDefault();
        var active_li = $('.li_active').removeClass('li_active').prev();
        if(!active_li.length) active_li = $('ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child');
        active_li.addClass('li_active').find('a').trigger('mouseenter');
        break;
      case 13:
        var value = $('ul.dropdown-menu .li_active').removeClass('li_active').attr('data-value');
        if (value && this.items[value]) {
          this.select(this.items[value]);
          this.hide();
        }
        break;
      default:
        this.request();
        break;
   }
});
```

To not interfere with the bootstrap `:hover` state, you will need to override CSS and add event handlers:

```
$(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu')
.on('click', 'a', $.proxy(this.click, this))
.on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    $('.li_active').removeClass('li_active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('li_active');
})
.on('mouseleave', 'a', function(){
    $('.li_active').removeClass('li_active');
});
```

CSS:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
  background : #ffffff;
}

ul.dropdown-menu .li_active, ul.dropdown-menu .li_active a:hover {
  background : #f5f5f5;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4jef9k29/10/)